# graphviz : How can I make the boxes so large that the texts are always inside?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Texts are written outside the box in graphviz. How can I make the boxes so large that the texts are always inside?

[image]

what is marked in red must be inside the box.

Update----------------------------------------

Dot Code

```
digraph UML_Class_diagram {
    graph [
        label="UML Class diagram"
        labelloc="t"
        fontname="Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
        splines=ortho, nodesep=1
        overlap=prism, overlap_scaling=0.1
    ]
    node [
        fontname="Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
        shape=record
        style=filled
        fillcolor=gray95

    ]
    edge [fontname="Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"]
    edge [arrowhead=vee style=solid]

ADN293[
shape=plain
label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr> <td> <b>CAx connector and function</b> </td> </tr><tr> <td>
<table align="left" border="0" cellborder="0" cellspacing="0" >
<tr> <td align="left" >+ loss performance relevant : Boolean : null</td> </tr>
<tr> <td align="left" >+ number of connectors : Integer (count) : ZeroToOne</td> </tr>
<tr> <td align="left" >+ Number of function groups : Integer (count) : null</td> </tr><tr> 
<td port="ss2" align="left" >- Function group : Reference</td> </tr></table> </td> </tr> 
</table>> ]
edge [dir=back arrowtail=diamond]ADN293:ss2 -> AAS252 [xlabel=null] ;AAS252     [
shape=plain

label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr> <td> <b>Function group</b> </td> </tr><tr> <td>
<table align="left" border="0" cellborder="0" cellspacing="0" >
<tr> <td align="left" >+ Number of functions : Integer (count) : null</td> </tr>
<tr> <td align="left" >+ type of function groups : String : null</td> </tr>
<tr> <td align="left" >+ Function group execution : String (translatable) : null</td> </tr>
<tr> <td align="left" >+ Function criterium : String : null</td> </tr><tr> <td align="left" >+ Number of parts relations : Integer (count) : null</td> </tr><tr> 
<td align="left" >+ Number of function groups : Integer (count) : null</td> </tr></table> </td> </tr> </table>> ]
edge [dir=back arrowtail=diamond]}
```

Comment: Please show the dot code that you used to generated this image

Comment: hallo @albert , now you could see the code. thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

No mentioning of the dot version or the output format, but with dot - graphviz version 7.0.5 (20221223.1930) and png output I see:

[image]

So here the text is inside the box, and the problem is probably a version problem.